# Why is variable length array forbidden: "C90 forbids variable length array"?

Tags: c, arrays, strlen

I know that I'm not supposed to do this in C90, and it's a rather basic stuff.

```
char name[strlen(s)];

ArrayLength.c:11: warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘name’
```

Did they want me to specifically use malloc? I'm just curios here about the logic behind it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634888/why-cant-i-initialize-a-variable-sized-array

This link Will be helpful to you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634888/why-cant-i-initialize-a-variable-sized-array

This link is same as for your doubt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's forbidden because C90 doesn't support variable-length arrays (VLAs).  It's really as simple as that.

Your options are:

- Declare a fixed-length array that can cope with the maximum string length you want to work with.
- Dynamically-allocate the array (using `malloc`).
- Work with a compiler that offers VLAs a non-standard language extension, e.g. GCC.  (I don't recommend this, because it means you'll end up writing non-portable code.)
- Use C99 instead, where VLAs are supported.  Note that VLAs are allocated on the stack, which can cause all sorts of issues if you run out of stack space (unlike with `malloc`, there's no concept of being able to check that the allocation was successful).

[***Note:*** If you're allocating an array in order to make a copy of `s`, you'll need to use `strlen(s)+1` as the size (remember the null terminator).]

Comment: +1 To add to this, `malloc` allocates memory on the heap, while C99's variable length arrays allocate memory on the stack (similar to the non-standard `alloca` function).

Answer (score 1):

It's not that "they" don't want you to do it, it's simply not part of the language (or rather, wasn't prior to 1999).  The standard workaround is to use `malloc` or `alloca`.  (`alloca` is essentially identical to variable length array allocation, but is not a standard function, so it may not be available on all systems of interest.  Also, some people have strong objections to it's use, but they tend to object strong to variable-length arrays for the same reasons.)

Comment: +1 for `alloca`, which I like. **But** typically you shouldn't (a) mix it with VLAs, (b) use it in loops, or (c) expect VLA `sizeof` semantics.

Answer (score 0):

This warning points to the usage of a GNU gcc extension is a serious portablity problem.

The code is illegal, because the value of strlen(s) is not known at compile time. GNU gcc provides an extension for automatic arrays that allocate based on run time values; but relying on these makes the code out of compliance with the standard.

If the value of strlen(s) isn't known until run-time then one can bring the code into compliance by either converting to performing the allocation/deallocation explicitly on conventions arrays, or by using STL containers.(e.g. std::vector).

Comment: VLAs are not an extension.  They have been standard C for 12 years now, and do not pose serious portability problems.  The warning only tells you that the code will not work with truly antediluvian compilers.

Comment: @StephenCanon: AFAICS, MSVC doesn't support VLAs.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: MSVC doesn't support C.  (I'm being snarky, but there's some truth to it.)

Comment: @StephenCanon: MSVC doesn't support C99 (it's a matter of opinion whether C99 == C nowadays).  Either way, regardless of one's opinions of MSVC's (lack of) standard support, it is a widely-used compiler.  If one is aiming to write cross-platform code, one should consider MSVC as a target.

Comment: @Oli I dare say Stephen counts that one as antediluvian.

Comment: Also, in C1x VLA support becomes an optional feature, so it’s nice to be warned about non-portable functionality.

Comment: @StephenCanon: VLA is allowed as a gcc extension in C90 mode, while emitting the warning in the topic.

Comment: @StephenCanon I really wish MSVC would support C99. It's been over a decade now. I'm a C++ developer but I can see the benefits of selectively using VLAs and C in some performance-critical areas as our profiler hotspots often come down to heap allocations/deallocations and VLAs are at least safer than MAX_BUFFER-type C89 solutions which either use too much of the stack or too little.

Comment: @StephenCanon: The Standard has never required that compilers generate useful code for VLAs.  It's pretty well accepted that trying to create a VLA that is too big can result in arbitrary behavior (typically as a consequence of overflowing the stack).  Since the Standard does not specify any means by which an application can guarantee that any particular size will not be "too big", nor does it mandate that implementations must be able to safely handle any particular minimum size, any VLA declaration may invoke UB in the absence of platform-specific guarantees. Mandating syntactic acceptance...

Comment: ...of a new construct without posing any requirements on its runtime behavior seems rather silly.  I'd suggest, btw, that int-to-pointer and pointer-to-int casts should be regarded as an optional feature on platforms which do not define uintptr_t, since there is no requirement that there exist any valid pointers whose representation will fit in any integer type.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of the language having restrictions for the presumed convenience of the
compiler and its intended runtime environment.