# String weirdness in C

Tags: c, string

I've just encountered a weird problem.

This code works:

```
int l = strlen(output); // l = 20 (believe me)
char withoutLeadingZeroes[20] = "";
```

and this doesn't:

```
int l = strlen(output); // l = 20 (believe me)
char withoutLeadingZeroes[l] = "";
```

I am getting this error

> Array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal

I really don't get that. Any suggestions?
Greetings from Vienna :-)

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work" ?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is almost never a useful explanation for a programming problem. What is the result you see?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634888/why-cant-i-initialize-a-variable-sized-array

Comment: You are quite right, sorry! I'm using Xcode (latest version) and the error says "Array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal".

Answer (score 2):

You can't initialize static array of any type in this way by using variable. It must be const, I believe.

VS2010:
    `error C2057: expected constant expression`

Comment: Not just a const either, a compile time constant, which aren't always the same thing necessarily.

Comment: well, I guess you're right. I didnt really focus on "const" as in keyword, but I should write it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep that in mind, although in this case "l" represents a value of 20.

Comment: @RainerSchmid, you may think so, but the compiler doesn't. And in the end it's the compilers opinion that matters.

Comment: @RainerSchmid is represents the value of 20 or.. any other value that fits an int. The compiler can't know beforehand what will be the value of `l`. (maybe it can if strlen() is used on a const string but then you will dependant on the compiler smarts)

Comment: @RainerSchmid The variable `l` has value `20` at run-time after the initialization; at compile-time, the value of `l` is unknown.  The length of the array must be known at compile-time, so this is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Online C99 Standard (n1256)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

> **6.7.8 Initialization**
> ...
> 3 The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or an object type
> that is not a variable length array type.

The declaration `char withoutLeadingZeroes[l] = "";` declares `withoutLeadingZeros` as a *variable-length array*, and attempting to initialize it as you're doing here is a constraint violation.

The diagnostic could be a bit clearer, though.

**Edit**

Can you point out *exactly* which line gets the error?  I get a much clearer diagnostic with gcc, and I *thought* XCode ran gcc under the hood.

Comment: Thank you. The error was: "Array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal" If I do "int l = 20" in the previous line I get the error too, but if I do "const int l = 20" it works. That's what I don't really understand. (The value of l is known at compile time!)

Comment: Whoa. Are you compiling this as C or C++?  And does the error give the exact line number?

Comment: Huh.  Apparently I'm wrong about XCode using gcc; since 3.2 it's been using LLVM and clang.  Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't support VLA (variable lenght arrays), maybe C99 onwards not sure in what C standard VLA got in.

suggestion:

```
int len = strlen(output);
char * wo_zeros = (char *)malloc(len);
strcpy(wo_zeros, "");
//do something with wo_zeros
free(wo_zeros);
```

Comment: You are quite right, sorry! I'm using Xcode (latest version) and the error says "Array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal".

Comment: It was my first post here, so I forgot a few essentials.