# Copying a static array to a dynamic array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to write a method that creates a course, and adds it to the static array of the SRS. however, my code gives no errors but doesn't add the course at all. What am i doing wrong?
By the way courses is dynamic array.

This code is correct now:

```
#include "StudentReviewSystem.h"

StudentReviewSystem::StudentReviewSystem()
{
    numberOfCourses = 0;
    courses = new Course[0];
}

void StudentReviewSystem::addCourse( const int courseId, const string courseName )
{
int i = findCourse( courseId );

 if ( i == -1 )
  {
  int newNum = numberOfCourses + 1;
  Course *newCourses = new Course[newNum];

  for ( int j = 0; j < numberOfCourses; j++ )
  {
     newCourses[j] = courses[j];
  }

   Course aCourse(courseId, courseName);

   newCourses[numberOfCourses] = aCourse;

   delete []courses;
   courses = newCourses;
   numberOfCourses = newNum; 

   cout<< "Course added"<< endl;
   }

   i = findCourse(courseId);
   cout<< i;
}
```

Thanks for help everyone!

Comment: This is not valid C++. C++ arrays must have a constant-expression size. You should use a `std::vector<Course>`.

Comment: How have you declared your courses array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in the code. in C++ when a variable is declared as an array the size of the array shall be a cobstabt expression. So this statement is invalid

```
Course newCourses [newNum];
```

In C/C++ there is no assignment operator for arrays. So this code is also invalid

```
courses = newCourses;
```

Also you forgot to change value of varaibale numberOfCourses. Shpuld be

```
numberOfCourses = newNum;
```

Also you may not enlarge arrays in C/C++.

Instead of using an array you should dynamically allocate memory. So courses should be defined as

```
Course *courses;
```

Taking into account other necessary changes the function would look the following way

```
void StudentReviewSystem::addCourse( const int courseId, const string courseName )
{
   int i = findCourse( courseId );

   if ( i == -1 )
   {
      int newNum = numberOfCourses + 1;
      Course *newCourses = new Course[newNum];

      for ( int j = 0; j < numberOfCourses; j++ )
      {
         newCourses[j] = courses[j];
      }

      Course aCourse(courseId, courseName);

      newCourses[numberOfCourses] = aCourse;

      delete []courses;
      courses = newCourses;
      numberOfCourses = newNum; 

      cout<< "Course added"<< endl;
   }

   i = findCourse(courseId);
   cout<< i;
}
```

Comment: (+1) there is at least a typo in your answer `cobstabt` second line

Comment: first this code didn't work. I've deleted `delete [] courses` and it started to work. is there any problem with doing that?

Answer (score 1):

```
Course newCourses [newNum];
```

This is not valid C++. `newNum` should be a compile time constant.

Also, I don't think you can directly equate two static arrays.

```
courses = newCourses;
```

Instead assign individual elements using a for loop, or better still, use `std::vector`.

Try the following code:

```
if(i == -1) {
        int newNum = numberOfCourses + 1;
        Course* newCourses = new Course[newNum];
        for(int j = 0; j < numberOfCourses; j++) {
            newCourses[j] = courses[j];
        }

        Course aCourse(courseId, courseName);

        newCourses[numberOfCourses] = aCourse;
        delete [] courses;
        courses = new Course[newNum];
        for(int j = 0; j < newNum; j++) {
            courses[j] = newCourses[j];
        }
        delete [] newCourses;
        cout<< "Course added"<< endl;
    }
```

Comment: Cources is  numberOfCourses and new cources is  numberOfCourses+1

Comment: I can't use vectors (our teacher doesn't allow). However, I used for loop to copy arrays.
Still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for help! But, I'm getting a runtime error in line `delete [] courses;`

Comment: `private:  Course* courses; int numberOfCourses;` in my header.

Comment: @EfeGürkan without `delete []`-ing the old courses array, you'll have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

```
int newNum = numberOfCourses + 1;
Course newCourses [newNum];
```

[is not legal c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634888/why-cant-i-initialize-a-variable-sized-array) and there's no need for copying from whatever array to another in your case. Just use a `std::vector` as a member of your class and use its [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) method.

Did your teacher explain you a reason for not using `std::vector`? If not, you'd better of thinking for yourself and trying your best to produce good software and not hacks. Implementing a dynamically sized container is possible. It it's the homework task, then there's no need to write the `StudentReviewSystem` class, but concentrate on implementing a dynamically sized array. If not, then you shouldn't reinvent two wheels at a time, but concentrate on one - the `StudentReviewSystem`, and use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You may create the array on heap using `new []`:

```
 Course* newCourses = new Course[newNum];
```

then copy as you already do and add the new course.
Don't forget to `delete` the old courses array

```
 delete [] courses;
 courses = newCourses;
```

and to update `numberOfCourses` (I think here is **your** error)

```
 numberOfCourses = newNum;
```

Comment: In my original code, I update numberOfcourses, but while trying to find the problem I accidentally deleted that line a guess ^^

Comment: @EfeGürkan did you try one of the dynamic versions meanwhile?

Comment: Yes. `delete [] courses` gives me runtime error. I'm trying to figure it out why.

Comment: `courses` should be initialized with `NULL` or with a dynamic array, this may be currently not the case. Would you please add the globals `courses` and `numberOfCourses` to your snippet as well.

Comment: I've added. I'm initliazing courses to size 0 array at first.