# How to make an unknow size array global?

Tags: c++, arrays

### Edit

Now I want to know if it is possible to make `ar` as a global variable supposing I'm using `g++`.

---

My confusion comes from [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22432815/2794152).

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    int ar[N] ={0};
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        std::cout << ar[i] << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code works perfectly fine. **so why saying that we can't do this?**

Besides, the real problem I want to solve is how can I make `ar` global?

```
#include <iostream>
int N;
int main() {
    std::cin >> N;
    int ar[N] ={0};
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        std::cout << ar[i] << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**The above code only set `N` to global, but if I want to make `ar` global, I don't know how to do**

Comment: It's nonstandard but supported by the g++ compiler through an extension

Comment: @awesomeyi What about second question, making it global?

Comment: @buzhidao *This code works perfectly fine* -- [No it doesn't](http://rextester.com/FDYGC28984).

Comment: @Cornstalks I know that, but I want to make `ar` global. So that when I using it in another function, I don't need to pass it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood that part. Well in that case you can't create a dynamically sized array. See the duplicate question and answer. You'll either have to dynamically allocate the array or use a container like `std::vector` (which will dynamically allocate it for you, provided you tell it what size to make it).

Comment: The first part of the code even does not work (at least in g++ 4.6.3). You can not have a variable sized array.