# allocating memory to an array of variable length

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, malloc

I want the length of this array to be taken as input from user.
let n be the entered length;
when I use malloc: `int *arr1[n] = malloc((sizeof(int) * n) + 1);`
it says a variable sized array can't be initialized, is there any other way to do it?

I want to take an array as input from the user, sort the elements of the array and store the sorted elements in another array. Here's my complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{    
    int temp = 0;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main(void)
{    
    int n = 0;
    printf("Enter the number of elements - ");
    scanf("%i", &n);
    int *arr1[n];
    int arr2[] = malloc((sizeof(int) * n) + 1);
    printf("Enter the elements one by one - ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%i", arr1[i]);
    }
    free(arr2);
}
```

I didn't declare the second array as arr2[n] as n is variable and it won't let me initialize the array with malloc. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: int *arr1[n] = malloc((sizeof(int) * n) + 1), why you make it as areay malloc just return generic pointer (pointer to void) location first address in the reserved block so just make it int *= (int*)malloc((sizeof(int) * n) + 1); now you have an array !.

Comment: Why the `+ 1` ? And what is `arr2` for? You don't use it at all?

Comment: make sure you're aware of the difference between `%i` and `%d` in scanf

Comment: This question has already been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634888/why-cant-i-initialize-a-variable-sized-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *other* way to do it, but there is a *correct* way:

You want this:

```
int arr1[n];
int *arr2 = malloc((sizeof(int) * n) + 1);
...
scanf("%i", &arr1[i]);
```